# Searching a word having capital letters from a paragraph using solr

Tags: php, solr

I am using solr for searching. When i search a word contains uppercase letters  from

description, its not showing any result. But it gives result for lowercase letters ..

Eg: If my query is q=description:* stack * , i will get the result . But if query is

q=description:* Stack * , it wont give any result evenif description contains that word

My schema contains :

```
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.TextField">
 <analyzer type="index">
  <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
  <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" />
 </analyzer>
 <analyzer type="query">
  <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
   <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I want to search with upper case letters also..

Can someone help me ?

Comment: can you please little more clear with your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Solr wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory). It says:

> Add this filter to the index analyzer, but not the query analyzer.

Try querying with `debugQuery=on` after you've changed the schema to reflect the wiki instructions:

```
<str name="querystring">text:*Stack*</str>
<str name="parsedquery">text:#1;*kcatS*</str>
```

As you can see, the `ReversedWildcardFilterFactory` changes your query even if it's not in your query analyzer chain, with a fieldType like this:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>           
        <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" />       
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>       
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>               
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Furthermore, the `LowerCaseFilterFactory` is not fired for your query (the `S` is not lowercase in the parsed query). The same happens for `ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory`.
Have a look [here](http://solr.pl/en/2010/12/20/wildcard-queries-and-how-solr-handles-them/) to know more:

> Solr does not analyze queries in which there are wildcards. Yes, this
>   means that the filter LowerCaseFilterFactory, during indexing,
>   turns Stack to stack but when making queries this is not happening, despite the
>   fact that the filters are defined correctly. And that is why you don't
>   get any search results.

The easiest solution that comes in my mind is making your queries lowercase on client side, before sending them to Solr. You should also consider that the `ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory` is not fired either. Do you really need it?

Comment: This worked? According to SOLR defect tracking (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2438), this issue is fixed in v3.6 and 4.0.

Comment: @MikePurcell My example shows how `ReversedWildcardFilterFactory` works: filters are not fired for wildcard queries. I just explained why it doesn't work and proposed a potential solution. I'm not sure how much SOLR-2438 is related to `ReversedWildcardFilterFactory`.

Comment: The OP stated he was unable to conduct a case sensitive wildcard search, which SOLR-2438 is directly related. I think what fixed his problem was your suggestion for him to lower the querystring on the clientid. Just wanted to make sure, for my own knowledge.

Comment: @MikePurcell Yeah, the only thing is that using `ReversedWildcardFilterFactory` makes things different I guess. Before answering I did some tests on Solr 3.5 using the field type mentioned in the question. Cheers!